# Wildcards in counter specifiers in Azure Diagnostic

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric, azure-diagnostics

What I am trying to achieve is similar to what you can see in [mongo-azure repo](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-azure/blob/master/src/MongoDB.WindowsAzure.MongoDBRole/diagnostics.wadcfg), specifically, I want to write Azure Diagnostic Configuration File in such a way so that I can get all the instances of performance counters, for example

> \Processor(*)\% Processor Time

and it doesn't seem to be working - no data is visible in the table in my storage account.

Is it achievable at all with configuration, and if so, how?

UPD: We were able to get this working for a simple single VM (so it is possible!), but for some reason it still doesn't work for VMs in VMSS where Service Fabric Cluster is running

UPD #2: We did upgrade to VS 2015 tools 1.5 and now it *magically* works. I am not really sure if that was the root cause problem or we screwed up anywhere else.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it achievable at all with configuration, and if so, how?

Based on the documentation [`here`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-services/cloud-services-dotnet-diagnostics-performance-counters), it seems it is not possible. From this link:

> #### Performance counters available for Microsoft Azure
>
> **Azure provides a subset of the performance counters available for
>   Windows Server, IIS and the ASP.NET stack**. The following table lists
>   some of the performance counters of particular interest for Azure
>   applications.

Table that follows below only includes `Processor(_Total)`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Though, the same paragraph says 'some', so I see that table as an example. Moreover, I do see the counters I am interested in, and even can get their values if list them all explicitly. What I am after is a 'generalized' way to specify counter

Answer (score 0):

This is possible.  We do this in [CloudMonix](http://cloudmonix.com) when monitoring VMSS and it is working.

How are you instrumenting Diagnostics and which tables are you looking at?

Specifying \LogicalDisk(*)\Available Megabytes yileds all drives and their free space, for example

Comment: We did upgrade to VS 2015 tools 1.5 and now it works. I am not really sure if that was the root cause problem or we screwed up anywhere else.  Thanks for your answer!